# Lowest bound of $S$ such that a set of $n$ known rectangles fit in an $S*S$ square.

Tags: geometry, area, rectangles

There is a set of $n$ rectangles with known dimensions. I want to find the smallest square that can fit all these rectangles within the following rules:

1) Rectangle sides must be parallel to $X$ or $Y$ axis.

2) Rotating rectangles is allowed.

3) Rectangles can touch but must not overlap.

I'm pretty sure no polynomial algorithm exists for such a problem, so I'm interested in some mathematical formula that gives a reasonable lowest bound of the square size.

Thanks.

Comment: A reasonable lowest bound? What is a "polynomial algorithm" for you?. What have you tried? Which is the distribution of the rectangles dimensions?. This question is unanswerable as is.

Comment: The best bound for your question is $\sqrt{\sum a_i^2}$